# Socket programming in mac os

Tags: macos

I need help for open socket in MAC OS Programming. I want to know how to call and connect with the socket so that i am able to open socket over the view by clicking on the button.

Thanks
Rana

Comment: What programming language are you working in?

Answer (score 0):

Cocoa provides NSStream class to communicate over socket, moreover if you are coming form Windows or C , objective C is super set of C , so socket API will also work, worth taking look at

[NSStream class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSStream_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score -1):

I heard about CFSocket.
I think, you can find it in google.

You can Open Socket or receiving data with CFSocket.

Comment: This is not a good answer. You should at least take the time to google it yourself and add a link. Also, provide an example on how to use it (or a link to the relevant part in the documentation).